# Как валидировать JSON

Tags: php, json

```
{\"breadcrumb\":[{\"titleTag\":\"ULTRAMARSCH 100km+ in unter 24 Stunden\",\"isVisible\":true,\"parents\":[],\"slug\":\"home\",\"href\":\"/\",\"metaDescription\":\"ULTRAMARSCH 100km+ in unter 24 Stunden - Speedhiking Extremwandern - Berlin, R\u00FCgen, Usedom, Schwarzwald, Dresden, L\u00FCneburger Heide, Erfurt\",\"title\":\"Home\",\"categoryId\":\"626B2E4C-4CD9-38E6-503D-0A0C6D0DA037\",\"objectId\":295177232,\"type\":\"category\",\"id\":\"256dc841-07e4-4cd2-bcbe-6cefa4f9c886\",\"children\":[]}],\"products\":{}}
```

**json_decode** возвращает ошибку синтаксиса JSON, что и логично.
Есть какой-то метод, убирающий эти экранирующие слэши?
я могу конечно их сам заменить, но хотелось бы знать как это штатными средствами делается

https://onecompiler.com/php/3z2n392vq

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: лучше разберитесь с тем, кто вам неправильный json формирует, а не как к одному костылю второй добавить.

Comment: Абсолютно верно!

Comment: @teran согласен, но не имею возможности)

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft, благодарствую! то, что надо!

Comment: Это вполне себе валидный json... Т.к. я уверен что по бокам слева и справа тоже двойные кавычки и здесь они убраны...